# How to restore the previous session in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin in which I want to restore the previous session so that I can have my data back when the browser is reopened.

I also have the timer facility in that plugin so timer should also be resume from where it is left at time time of closing the browser.

Comment: well I tried to save the session id in cookie. But I don't know how to retrieve it back to store all previous data?

Comment: Once a session is expired, the data should be considered gone. So the simple solution is: don't make your sessions expire. Set the session lifetime to a correct value and the session cookie lifetime to the same and you should be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plugin will need to extend the length of the server's PHP session length and the expiry of the cookie containing the session id, so that the user coming back will still have access to the non-expired session. (Similar to Gerard's comment).

If you want to restore a different PHP session (say a user logs in as user A, then logs out and in as user B, then logs out and wants to login again as user A and keep their session info from their first login), you might want to store the php session id as a user meta value along with an expiry timestamp of some sort. You will have to be pretty careful in considering security implications (which I won't get into as it isn't part of the question).